# How to get the nearest Tuesday to April 1st every year?

Tags: r, date

I have got a question relating to Date. I need to determine the date, which is the nearest Tuesday to April 1st, in each year from 1961 to 2006.

As I can check from Calendar, I see the following:

```
1961    1961-04-04
1962    1962-04-03
1963    1963-04-02
1964    1964-03-31
```

But, instead of eye spotting them from a Calendar, can I do this easily in R?

---

The question has a background in air pollution network management. Specifically, the historical Smoke and Sulphur Dioxide Network in the UK operating between 1961 and 2005 was managed on a "pollution year" basis, and such year stars from the date mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one solution

```
nearestTuesday <- function(date) {
  delta <- as.POSIXlt(date)$wday - 2
  if(abs(delta) < 4) 
    next_date <- as.Date(date) - delta
  else 
    next_date <- as.Date(date) + (7 - delta)
  return(next_date)
}

lapply(ISOdate(1961:2006, 4,1), nearestTuesday)
```